# rails openssl issue in fedora 14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedora, webrick

I have installed ruby by downloading and compiling the source... when i run script/server in my rails application.. it throws an error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:271:in `require_frameworks': no such file to load -- openssl (RuntimeError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:134:in `process'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
        from /home/mohit/install/elitmus-campus/config/environment.rb:16
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from script/server:3
```

when i do yum install openssl.

it shows openssl-1.0.0c-1.fc14.i686 already installed and latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `yum install openssl-devel`

Comment: This. Then reconfigure and recompile Ruby. Check the output of your configure command to see if it is configured to build OpenSSL support.